# How to join RDDs based on elastic-hadoop

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, elasticsearch, hdfs, bigdata

I'm looking for ways to process parallel data from large index,
I thought about snapshot the index (to hdfs) and then submit spark jobs to process the records.

Other way to solve it, is to use [elastic with spark](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/hadoop/2.3/spark.html).

My questions:

1. Can the snapshot API output be text file instead of binary files?
2. How can I use spark-elastic and perform sub queries for a specific document? (lets say I have index of dogs and then I want to find the bones of each dog)?

**------EDIT------**

My indexes changed a little, There is Dogs indexes, an dogs-relation index. 
Dogs index:

```
...
{
  name: "rex",
  id: 1,
  ...
},
{
  name: "bobby",
  id : 2,
  ...
}
...
```

Dogs relation Index:

```
...
{
   first_dog_id: 1,
   second_dog_id: 2,
   relation_type: "enemies",
   ...
}
...
```

The relation is many-to-many, so each dog can have many documents in dogs-relation index. I would like to create 2 RDDs (dogs & relation) and somehow join them in memory without broadcast the data (large indexes)

Comment: Regarding 2., I think I would read the dog data, and the bones data into memory in Spark first rather than hitting ES each time you give a dog a bone.

Comment: @ImDarrenG how can I merge this 2 lists in memory? how can I run over partitions of the first RDD and query on the second RDD?

Comment: My first intuition is to join the RDDs by some key, but assuming that won't work, please provide more information about your use-case otherwise we're just guessing?

Comment: @ImDarrenG, I updated the question..

Comment: How much data is there - too much to fit into memory on your spark cluster? And what are you trying to achieve with your spark job?

Comment: It is millions of documents so it is too large for memory. I would like to calculate something based on the dog document and his relations (all his documents in the second index). some kind of "join" by dog_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Pt 1.**

I don't think so, AFAIK the closest option would be to use the scan/scroll API (depend on which ES version you are on): [ES v5.1 scroll api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-scroll.html).
 You can 'export' your indexes to text file/s that way.

**Pt 2.**

The simplest way - code-wise - to do what you want (elasticsearch query per dog document), would be to load your dogsRDD using elastic-hadoop, then for the sub-query behaviour, do something like:

```
dogsRDD.mapPartitions { dogsPart =>
    // this code is executed by the workers
    dogsPart.map { dog =>
        // do the dog specific ES queries here
    }
}
```

But, you won't be able to use `elastic-hadoop` to do your dog-specific work like this, you'll have to use a scala ES connector, or HTTP, and the ES scan/scroll api.

You will probably be able to improve on this with more specific knowledge of the use-case you have, maybe you can split the work over multiple managable steps idk.

Probably not helpful this late in your life-cycle, but I have some observations that I would like to make in the most constructive possible way:

- I don't know all the details obviously, but, that you are reasoning about your documents in relational terms suggests that the existing data model is going to cause more headaches. ES doesn't do joins.
- Consider making life easier at query-time by performing some aggregations at write-time
- Reading between the lines, it sounds like you have one big index? If appropriate, you might do better splitting into smaller indexes.  I've had success using time-based indexes. i.e. an index per day, or month, depending on how much data.
- Again, probably not very helpful, but Spark does best when the data you work with fits into the memory of the cluster, or the job can be reasonably broken up into, say, time-based 'shards'. Or maybe break the job down by writing the output of each step to disk to free up memory.  I know it all depends on the use-case!
- ElasticSearch primary use-case is querying, in my experience it's not great for batch/bulk processing use-cases.

Just thought I'd share some of my findings in case it's useful in some small way. :)